# Calling a scala libraray from java code

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I am using the scala library https://github.com/ing-bank/scruid in my java code.There are examples to use the library from scala. Can someone help me quickly to convert the same call in java. 
The call in scala is (mentioned in the Readme of the library as well)

```
case class TimeseriesCount(count: Int)

val result = TimeSeriesQuery[TimeseriesCount](
  aggregations = List(
    CountAggregation(name = "count")
  ),
  granularity = "hour",
  intervals = List("2011-06-01/2017-06-01")
).execute
```

Here TimeSeriesQuery is a case class from the library Scruid.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the same call"? Please add the relevant code. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I mentioned the usage of the library from a scala class. I have a java application and i want to use the same library in my code. How do i make the same call to the execute method of scala case class TimeSeriesQuery from java. I am new to scala and so have problems in understanding all the scala code.

Comment: It's a library written by 2 (two) people, without any indication that they want to provide a Java API. So you will have to re-wrap your parameters into `List`s, and unpack the query results into `LinkedList`s. Same with all `Option`s and other scala-specific stuff. Java doesn't have named method params, so you'll have to implement tons of builder-patterns. You'll have to provide implicit `Manifest`s to the `execute` method (aren't those deprecated anyway?). And then, you didn't even get to the case-class-reflection-deserialization magic. Use Scala directly. Or contribute a Java API to scruid.

Comment: More important: I don't get what this library buys you except a thin layer of Scala-specific syntactic sugar over json-queries. How are you using it in your Java code at all? You cannot use Scala's syntactic sugar in Java code, that's for sure. But what else does the library provide anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Add conversion between scala and java

```
import scala.Option;
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
```

In java code, you can use scala case class:

```
List<Aggregation> agg = new ArrayList<>();
agg.add(new CountAggregation("count"));
List<String> intervals = Arrays.asList("2011-06-01/2017-06-01");
Optional<String> opt = Optional.of("option");
TimeSeriesQuery<TimeseriesCount> query = new TimeSeriesQuery<>(
            "hour",
            "a",
            "false",
            JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(agg.iterator()).toList(),
            Option.empty(),
       JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(intervals.iterator()).toList());

 query.execute();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Really, this compiles? That seems to address the "wrap the inputs to Scala-collections" part. It doesn't convert the result list back to java. Have you tried to get a result and use it as an `TimeseriesCount`? I don't see how it is supposed to instantiate a `TimeseriesCount` from the erased type annotation alone, where is anything `Class`- or `Manifest`-like? I'd at least expect a `ClassCastException`. You might want to check that it actually returns a `List<TimeseriesCount>` and not a `List<Object>` or something like that.